# Analysis on vs. of

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

Oftentimes, I saw both "analysis of" and "analysis on" on a website or news.

After searching for a while, I think "analysis of" is correct.

then, Can't I use analysis on?

What is the difference in the meaning?

For example, 
1. I performed an analysis of this phenomenon.
2. I performed an analysis on this phenomenon.

Thank you.

Comment: You perform analysis ON an object.  You perform analysis OF a concept.  Are you treating the website as an object, analyzing it's HTML structure, or on the website's concepts -- politics, audience, etc?

Comment: @HotLicks That actually is _part_ of a good answer..should we do the real thing, or delete the  Q?

Comment: @Rattler - You are welcome to take it and elaborate.  It's getting too close to my bedtime.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28351/analysis-on-vs-analysis-of).

It would be even better to say **I analyzed the phenomenon** and then you don't have to worry about it :)

Comment: Why did you downvote me?